# Show domain/sub-dirictory1 on sub-domain1.domain (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to use subdomains instead of subfolders. Unfortunately, since my host doesn't allow wildcard subdomains in my dns settings, I couldn't do a subdomain install. I do however think that I should be able to achieve this post-install, since I can manually make subdomains.

I have now made two subdomains: Subdom1 and Subdom2. My set-up at this point is domain/Subdir1 and domain/Subdir2. I'd like to have my visitors (and ideally also Google) to visit my site as subdom1.domain.com and subdom2.domain.com, both should show what is in the two subdirs.

I think this should be possible with .htaccess rules, but I'm hardly the expert at that. I'm hoping someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, obviously replace blog with your subdomain name

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1
```

more here http://terriswallow.com/weblog/2008/htaccess-redirect-a-directory-to-a-subdomain-and-force-www/

Comment: Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.be [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.be$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/alpha/(.*)$
http://alpha.domain.be/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/beta/(.*)$
http://beta.domain.be/$1

Tweaked it a bit to this, but it worked, thanks!